# JPA @ManyToOne CascadeType.PERSIST

Tags: jpa, weblogic12c, many-to-one

Hallo I have an entity with a @ManyToOne Relations ship

```
@Entity
public class TerminEntity extends AbstractEntity implements Serializable {


    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PERSON_ID")
    private PersonEntity person;

@MappedSuperclass   
public abstract class AbstractEntity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "termineIdGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="termineIdGenerator", sequenceName =    "SEQ_TERMINVERWALTUNG")
   private Long id;
```

When I try to persist a TerminEntity with an PersonEntity which is not already present in the database I get

java.lang.IllegalStateException: During synchronization a new object was found through a relationship that was not marked cascade PERSIST: TerminEntity(person=PersonEntity

Why? What is wrong with the @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST) annotation?

Running on Oracle Weblogic 12c

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but after changing the annotation to

```
@ManyToOne(optional = false, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE,   CascadeType.REFRESH })
@JoinColumn(name = "PERSON_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", nullable = false)
```

the persist works.